# How can I solve limit problems without graphing

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

If we have$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{1-e^x} = -\infty$$

What is a good way to solve this without the need to graph the function

Comment: Look at the [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F%281-e%5Ex%29) of $\frac{1}{1-e^x}$, especially as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x>0$, then $e^x>1$, and therefore $1-e^x<0$. So, since $\lim_{x\to0^+}1-e^x=0$,$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{1-e^x}=-\infty.$$

Answer (score 3):

The ${+}$ part of ${\lim_{x\to 0^+}}$ means that $x$ is getting smaller, but it is still always positive. For example, you could plug in some numbers,
$$
\frac{1}{1-e^{0.1}}\approx \frac{1}{-0.105}\approx -9.51
$$
$$
\frac{1}{1-e^{0.01}}\approx \frac{1}{-0.01005}\approx -99.5
$$
and so on. As you pointed out, ${e^x}$ is approaching $1$, but ${e^x > 1}$ for any positive $x$, and thus ${1 - e^x < 0}$ for any positive $x$. It then follows ${\frac{1}{1-e^x}}$ has to be negative for any positive $x$.